# Creating distinct buttons with different styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal

I am trying to make two different buttons for different modules. I have an accordion that uses a button to make it expand/collapse, and I have another button that you click to add up a bunch of numbers. The issue is that even though I named the button to add up numbers a separate name, the button style from the accordion carries over.
Here is what I am using for the adding up the numbers button.
```

```
<style media="screen">
.addbutton {
    padding: 1 px;
    height: 40 px;
    width: 10 px;
}

fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 20 px;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<body>
<h>Input Scores for Each Criterion:<br></h> 
<fieldset>
    1:
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    2: 
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    3: 
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    4: 
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select> 
    <br>
    <button type = "addbutton" id="btnInsert" onclick="onClick()">Add score!</button>
</fieldset>
<br> <br>
<fieldset>
    Score:
    <div id="lsOutput">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>

<script>
    let selectArray = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
    let number = 0;
    const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
    const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
    const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
    const lsOutput = document.getElementById("lsOutput");
    localStorage.setItem("total",number);
    localStorage.removeItem("total",number)
    function onClick () {
        lsOutput.innerHTML = ''
        number = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < selectArray.length;i++){
            number+= parseInt(selectArray[i].value);
        } 
        localStorage.setItem("total",number);
        lsOutput.innerHTML += number;
    };

</script>
```

When I run it independently, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MutlQ.png 
But when I add it to the website (Drupal custom block) I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vkux.png

In the accordion styling, I do have it named after "button," but even if I change the name the styling still carries over to the addbutton.

```
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 53px;
  width: 500px;
}
button:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: first of all, you are accessing ```.addButton``` as a class in your CSS but in dom the class name is not specified (you are confusing it with type).  Second it's really hard to replicate your code given you have 2 styles files with different elements which don't exist. I suggest you edit your question to get a proper answer.

Comment: @seriously Not really sure what you mean. The reason I have 2 style files is that they are separate modules in Drupal, the website builder. Should I perhaps have 1 instead? And what is "dom"? Thanks.

Comment: DOM means the document of origin your HTML initialized. and having 2 style files isn't a problem as long as you are calling it to your dom properly. but the main issue is not calling your elements properly in CSS. If you define your element with class name call it with the class name you, for example, addButton is called as a class in CSS but in your HTML it's a type hence it wont work. change ```type``` to ```class``` in html. do you get what I mean?

Comment: @seriously Ok, I think I'm going to have to review CSS. Thanks.